# Ajuda Formulário PHP

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php

// Do not edit this if you are not familiar with php
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
$post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;
if($post) {
    function ValidateEmail($email){

        $regex = "^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$^";
        $eregi = preg_replace($regex,'', trim($email));

        return empty($eregi) ? true : false;
    }

    $name = stripslashes($_POST['ContactName']);
    $to = trim($_POST['to']);
    $email = strtolower(trim($_POST['ContactEmail']));
    $subject = stripslashes($_POST['subject']);
    $message = stripslashes($_POST['ContactComment']);
    $error = '';
    $Reply=$to;
    $from=$to;

    // Check Name Field
    if(!$name) {
        $error .= 'Please enter your name.<br />';
    }

    // Checks Email Field
    if(!$email) {
        $error .= 'Please enter an e-mail address.<br />';
    }
    if($email && !ValidateEmail($email)) {
        $error .= 'Please enter a valid e-mail address.<br />';
    }

    // Checks Subject Field
    if(!$subject) {
        $error .= 'Please enter your subject.<br />';
    }

    // Checks Message (length)
    if(!$message || strlen($message) < 3) {
        $error .= "Please enter your message. It should have at least 5 characters.<br />";
    }

    // Let's send the email.
    if(!$error) {
        $messages="From: $email <br>";
        $messages.="Name: $name <br>";
        $messages.="Email: $email <br>";    
        $messages.="Message: $message <br><br>";
        $emailto=$to;

        $mail = mail($emailto,$subject,$messages,"from: $from <$Reply>\nReply-To: $Reply \nContent-type: text/html");    

        if($mail) {
            echo 'success';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<div class="error">'.$error.'</div>';
    }

}
?>
```

Alguém sabe me dizer onde eu devo entrar com o meu endereço de e-mail para receber os dados deste formulário?

Answer (score 0):

Vejo que não conhece bem a função [mail](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mail.php) do php

```
mail(string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]]);
```

`$to` = Receptor do email em questão

No seu código `$emailto=$to;` refere-se ao receptor, `$to`está vindo da `$_POST` de outro formulário

> Alguém sabe me dizer onde eu devo entrar com o meu endereço de e-mail para receber os dados deste formulário?

Você pode enviar uma cópia para você colocando o seu email como um dos destinatários:

```
$to=trim($_POST['to']).',';
$to.='seu@email.com';
```

Ou pode alterar para enviar apenas para o seu email, neste caso seria interessante retirar a `input[name='to']` do formulário que envia informações para este email

```
$to='seu@email.com';
```

Simplesmente alterando a linha 16 do seu código